# how to set inistial state for html editor material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, editor

I have this `<h1>header</h1>` and I want to set it as Intial state for htlm editor .I use this library **react-mui-draft-wysiwyg** https://openbase.com/js/react-mui-draft-wysiwyg/documentation#usage .Someone can help me?

Comment: if you are mentioning about initializing editor with some text, this [link](https://kelsier90.github.io/react-mui-draft-wysiwyg/examples/basic-with-content) may help you, check `text: 'Hello World'`

Comment: TypeError: draft_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12___default(...) is not a function

Comment: I applied the solution you sent but I will get this error

Comment: perhaps you are importing a draft-js component in wrong way, codesandbox in answer section could be  helpful

Comment: Yes, that was my problem.but convert <h1>hello</h1> to format rawContent ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Code Solution** https://codesandbox.io/s/estilos-editor-forked-gvef9?file=/src/editor.js

used https://kelsier90.github.io/react-mui-draft-wysiwyg/examples/basic-with-content
from documentation

```
import React from "react";
import MUIEditor, { MUIEditorState } from "react-mui-draft-wysiwyg";
import { convertFromRaw } from "draft-js";

const Editor = () => {
  const editorConfig = {};
  const rawContent = {
    blocks: [
      {
        data: {},
        depth: 0,
        entityRanges: [],
        inlineStyleRanges: [],
        key: "2vm6d",
        text: "Header",
        type: "header-one"
      }
    ],
    entityMap: {}
  };
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    MUIEditorState.createWithContent(editorConfig, convertFromRaw(rawContent))
  );
  const onChange = (newState) => {
    setEditorState(newState);
  };
  return <MUIEditor editorState={editorState} onChange={onChange} />;
};

export default Editor;
```

check if this can help you, Thanks ,

Comment: thank you .it work.but how to convert <h1>hello</h1> to rawContent ?

Comment: just replace text inside blocks:[{text:"hello"}]
and <h1> will be type:"header-one"

Comment: I get it from the server.And it is not always so short and simple